# What data-structure and format should I have data ready to be displayed on mouse-over

Tags: php, javascript

I am working on this test page: http://www.problemio.com/index_new.php and you see the categories that are listed.  They have associated sub-categories.

So what I want to have happen is if a person mouses-over on "Health" I want to present them with a list like:

```
- Personal Health
- Healthcare
- Diet
- Exercise
```

and there is a different sub-list for each category.

So my question is - since mouseOver looks like this: `onmouseover="SomeJavaScriptCode"`

I will likely have to call a JavaScript function, correct? If so, how do I populate the JS with the data from my PHP query? Should I create the JS during from my PHP since the data is dynamic? What approach is the best here?

Thanks!!

Comment: Off topic, but I would suggest using jQuery as your javascript lib. You'll save yourself a lot of effort concerning common javascript tasks.

Comment: @Kenaniah already using jQuery just didn't see how it would help in this case...what did you have in mind with it?

Comment: `$().ready(function(){ $.delegate("<selector">, "click", function() { $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").toggle(); }); });` or something like that.

Comment: I would call this thing a "Menu".  Search for suckerfish or son of suckerfish menus in google for simple and nice menus.

Comment: I agree. jquery is really great and does all things, and is good too, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach that is commonly used is to get the data in php, call [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to make the object in javascript then have separate scripts which will handle the user interaction keeping the data separate from the behavior. In javascript to get the object make the call shown [here](http://www.json.org/js.html) and then you can do whatever you want in javascript.

you can do this in php

```
print "<script>";
print "var myObject = eval('".json_encode($data)."');"
print "</script>";
```

and then the data is in javascript for other scripts do display as they like.

Comment: interesting...so when I have the data in PHP - how should I have it? A seperate array that I should encode for every mouse over?

Comment: ah ok, and the $data here would be what? I need to eventually display it as a link to a category page with the category name being the anchor text of the link. How could I do that?

Comment: I mean on mouse-over I'll need to display the approproate list of links to the sub categories.  How do I accomplish that?  Huge thanks!

Comment: typically you will just have your data in an array and using this method you can shoot it over to javascript.  You want to separate the behavior and the data so don't worry about the javascript behavior when you are working on getting the data in php.  Just worry about moving the data from php into a form javascript can understand then worry about how to display the data in javascript.  To actually do the displaying use the things that everyone else is posting as answers. (hover is your friend here in jquery)

Comment: ok srry I didn't get what you were asking before.  You want $data to be an array like this:  array(array('name'='namevalue1','link'=>'linkvalue1'),array('name'='namevalue2','link'=>'linkvalue2'),array('name'='namevalue3','link'=>'linkvalue3')) etc. then javascript can handle the printing the links and the names associated with them.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like nested `<ul>`'s would do the trick. I think it would make sense to output the entire list from PHP, but hide the sub-menus via CSS in your HTML. You could use either a click handler or mouseover / mouseout combo, but the javascript event handler would simply show / hide the sub-menu. That said, jQuery has a nice set of transition effects you can make use of.

Comment: You mean make a div, and make it display:none; and then on mouse over display it as a jQuery dialog?

Comment: @GeekedOut if that's what you want to do, sure. Main point being the HTML document has everything it needs already there (no need to AJAX for data).

Answer (score 1):

I agree, jQuery will become your best friend for tasks like this.

To structure your data in the HTML, I would use unordered lists. Something like:

```
<ul id="ph">
    <li>Personal Health
        <ul id="phsub1">
            <li>Item 1 in Personal health submenu</li>
            <li>...etc</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Healthcare <ul>...</ul></li>
    <li>etc</li>
</ul>
```

Like Kenaniah says, you can load them all and just hide them until mouseover.

```
$('ul#ph li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first-child').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first-child').hide();
});
```

Comment: thanks - one point of confusion though. I think as it looks now, the show() function would just show it. But I'd like to make it into a kind of a pop up that pops up over the link that is moused over...maybe with a dialog box.  Is that doable?

Comment: So you want a mouseover to cause a dialog popup to open? No offense, but that sounds kind of annoying from a UX pov. You can definitely animate the show / hide, with sliding, fading, or custom animations though.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is generate output to the html file, and use generic javascript that can apply to any similar element.

Here's an example (assuming PHP generated the following HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>

.outer {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#0F0;

    margin:10px;
}

.header {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
}
.inner_content, .inner_content_expanded {
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    float:top;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.inner_content {
    height:0px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- PHP would generate these elements and their contents -->
<div class="outer" onmouseover="expand(this);" onmouseout="contract(this);">
    <h3 class="header">One</h3>
    <div class="inner_content">
        A<br>
        B<br>
        C<br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="outer" onmouseover="expand(this);" onmouseout="contract(this);">
    <h3 class="header">Two</h3>
    <div class="inner_content">
        A<br>
        B<br>
        C<br>
    </div>
</div>




<script type="text/javascript">
function expand(element) {
    element.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].className = "inner_content_expanded";
}
function contract(element) {
    element.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].className = "inner_content";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```